# How to replace every element in a given list to its square and not create a new list with the squares

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a function that takes a list of integers and replaces the elements in the list with their respective squares.

I tried reassigning every element by virtue of its position (index) in the list, but for some reason the second element in the list gets squared twice.

```
def square_list(list1):
    for i in list1:
        list1[list1.index(i)] = i**2
    print(list1)

square_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I expect the printed list to be `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]` since the list I'm testing the function with is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`map`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map) built-in function is good for this, so you don't really have to write your own function.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l = list(map(lambda x: x**2, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function is required to square list elements in-place, use it:

```
def square_list(list_1):
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        list_1[i] = list_1[i]**2


my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
square_list(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

Since the function doesn't return anything, `square_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` is useless.